# Estimation of scaling exponent in the wavelet leaders multi-fractal formalism

Tags: wavelet, discrete-wavelet-transform, pywavelets

I am trying to extract multi-fractal features from time-series data
by estimating the singularity spectrum using the wavelet leaders multi-fractal formalism (WLMF) method. Specifically, I want to be able to extract the holder exponents and the fractal dimensions. I am using NumPy together with PyWavelets to compute the discrete wavelet transform (DWT) coefficients. I have the following contrived example of a signal with 32 timesteps:

```
import numpy as np
import pywt

signal = np.array([8.12132034,    6.70710678,   1.94974747,  -5.12132034,
                   11.94974747,   0.63603897,  -2.58578644,  -6.82842712,
                   7.4246212 ,   -5.30330086,   5.83883476,  -9.71751442,
                   12.04594155,  -7.75304833,  -3.02512627,  -8.68198052,
                   13.69238816,  -1.86396103,   2.32842712,  -0.5       ,
                   7.        ,    2.75735931,  -0.17157288,  -10.07106781,
                   3.03553391,   -2.62132034,   6.39949494,  -11.98528137,
                   2.        ,   -0.82842712,  -5.29289322,  -9.53553391])
```

The DWT coefficients for 5 levels using Daubechies wavelet of order four is computed as

```
coeffs = pywt.wavedec(signal, 'db1', level=5)
cA5, cD5, cD4, cD3, cD2, cD1 = coeffs

np.set_printoptions(precision=5)
for i, c in enumerate([cD1, cD2, cD3, cD4, cD5]):
     print(f"level: 2^{i+1} |" , "coefficients", c)
```

output:

```
level: 2^1 | coefficients [1.  5.  8.  3.  9. 11. 14.  4. 11.  2.  3.  7.  4. 13.  2.  3.]
level: 2^2 | coefficients [9. 11.  3.  8.  5. 10.  3.  8.]
level: 2^3 | coefficients [3. 2. 5. 3.]
level: 2^4 | coefficients [6. 8.]
level: 2^5 | coefficients [2.]
```

While there exist a few sources in WLMF method, i'll use the steps described in [this paper](https://www.irit.fr/%7EHerwig.Wendt/data/Domingues2019ISBI.pdf).

The first step is to compute the *wavelet leaders*, defined as
$$
L_X(j,k) \equiv L_{\lambda} = \underset{\lambda' \subset 3\lambda_{j,k}}{\text{sup}} |d_X(j,k)|
$$
where $d_X(j,k)$ is the dwt coefficients of the signal, $j$ is the analysis scale, $k$ is the time and $\lambda'$ is the time neighborhood. In rough terms this is computing the maximum absolute coefficient on each level in the dyadic interval and its two neighbors. The wavelet leaders for given coefficients can be computed in python with

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
import itertools as it

def L(coeffs):
  d = [
      sliding_window_view(x, (min(3*j, len(x)),))[:: 2**(j-1)] 
      for x,j in zip(coeffs, range(len(coeffs), -1, -1))
  ]
  return np.array([max(it.chain(*x)) for x in zip(*d)])
```

and the wavelet leaders for all five levels is computed as:

```
for i in range(1,6):
  print(f"level: 2^{i+1} |", "wavelet leaders ", L([cD1, cD2, cD3, cD4, cD5][:i]))
```

output:

```
level: 2^1 | wavelet leaders  [ 8.  8.  9. 11. 14. 14. 14. 11. 11.  7.  7. 13. 13. 13.]
level: 2^2 | wavelet leaders  [11. 14. 14. 14. 13. 13.]
level: 2^3 | wavelet leaders  [14. 14.]
level: 2^4 | wavelet leaders  [14.]
level: 2^5 | wavelet leaders  [14.]
```

The wavelet leaders for multiple levels form the structure function  $S(j,q)$, which are time averages of the $q$-th power of wavelet leaders at each scale:
$$
S(j,q) = \frac{1}{n_j} \sum_{k=1}^{n_j} |L_X(j,k)|^q \approx 2^{j \zeta(q)}
$$
where $n_j$ is the number of wavelet leaders at scale $j$ and $\zeta(q)$ is the scaling function (or scaling exponents). In [another paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0165168408004106), the scaling function $\zeta(q)$ is defined as
$$
\zeta(q) = \underset{2^j \to 0}{\text{lim}} \text{inf}\left( \frac{\ln S(j, q)}{\ln 2^j} \right)
$$
which in practice is estimated by linear regression:
$$
\hat{\zeta}(q) = \sum_{j=j_1}^{j_2} w_j \log_2 S(j,q)
$$
where $w_j$ is the weights.

Using my contrived example, I can follow how the structure function $S(j,q)$ is computed, but I can't follow how the estimation procedure for $\zeta(q)$ is done with linear regression. Which values does it interpolate on? How would the function $\zeta$ look using python code?